# Pyspark - Averaging values for every data batch of Kafka Streams

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm using **Pyspark** and **Kafka** to process data via live streams

I made a function that reads Kafka stream by batch and calculate the **average values** of data for each batch.

I want the same thing but when the values for the second batch should be the average of values for the first and the second batch (the **whole history** I mean). For the third batch, the average should be the average for the first + second + third batch.. etc

For more, If the first batch could be **updated** with new values calculated with the values of the last batch, that would be great :)

This is what I've done so far :

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json, time, os.path


kafka_brokers = "localhost:9092"
kafka_core_topic = "test"


sc = SparkContext(appName = "test-kafka")
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 3)
kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [kafka_core_topic], {"metadata.broker.list": kafka_brokers})

parsed = kvs.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1]))

@pandas_udf('double')
def mean_score(col):
    return pd.Series([np.mean(col)] * len(col))

def getSparkSessionInstance(sparkConf):
if ("sparkSessionSingletonInstance" not in globals()):
    globals()["sparkSessionSingletonInstance"] = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .config(conf = sparkConf)\
        .getOrCreate()
return globals()["sparkSessionSingletonInstance"]

def process(time, rdd):
    print("========= %s =========" % str(time))
    parquetfile = "sparkstream.parquet"

    spark = getSparkSessionInstance(rdd.context.getConf())

    schema = StructType([
        StructField('name', StringType()),
        StructField('score', IntegerType())
    ])

    data = spark.read.json(rdd, schema = schema)

    data = data.withColumn('mean_score', mean_score(data['score']))

    data.show()

    if os.path.isdir(parquetfile):
        data.write.mode('append').parquet(parquetfile)
    else:
        data.write.parquet(parquetfile)


parsed.foreachRDD(process)

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

This gives the following result :

[image]

Thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: I don't think Spark allows you to natively maintain results of a previous batch. If you want to have this type of srateful processing, you need a database that supports updates (like what Kafka Streams does with RocksDB), not a parquet file that only appends

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007 :(